# How to call parent table view method from a cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell with a label that should trigger a method of parent/table view controller.

Even though XCode provides me that method in autocomplete suggestions, it throws an error when  I tap on that particular label:

```
UITableViewWrapperView showUserProfile unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

This is my code:

```
    @implementation ItemTableViewCell

    @synthesize item;

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        self.authorLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showUserProfile)];
        [self.authorLabel addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }

    - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    }

    - (void)showUserProfile
    {
        id parentView = [self superview];
        [parentView showUserProfile];
    }

    @end
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to decouple your custom cell from your table view controller you should use [`NSNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 I asked you to delete a question you asked 5 minutes ago, that was in error. Please undelete your question.

Comment: @duci9y I closed the question page and it's not listed anymore in my account. Do you know if there is a way for me to do it now or only moderators / people with 10k+ rep can do it?

Comment: You own your content, there must be a way to do it. If not, I suggest you ask the question again, because there was a problem in your code that needed to be addressed. Calling `reloadData` was NOT the correct solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not the good way to passing some actions to the tableview. You must use a delegate between the custom class  UITableViewCell and your controller.

In your custom UITableViewCell.h

```
@protocol myUITableViewCellDelegate

@interface myUITableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<myUITableViewCellDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol myUITableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) cellDidTap:(myUITableViewCell*) sender
@end
```

In your custom UITableViewCell.m

```
...
- (void)showUserProfile
    {
        [self.delegate cellDidTap:self];
    }
...
```

In your controller

```
-(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexpath
{
......
        cell.delegate = self
......
}

-(void) cellDidTap:(myUITableViewCell*) sender
{
        [self showUserProfile];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; however I'm not sure if I understand how to implement this, specifically the part that should go into `UITableVIewCell.h`. Could you point me to either documentation or some tutorial with an example please?

Comment: It necessary to create an inherited UITableViewCell class. The way for it depend if you use Storyboard or Xib interface builder. You can found many tutorial for this,
search "create custom UITableViewCell".

Comment: Thanks again; will check it and post back.

Comment: Took me some time to wrap my head around it and do it a few times on test apps :D I got it now - thanks @tdelepine!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the controller (your ViewController that hosts UITableView for example) to your customized cell. Then, you use something like:

```
if ([self.controller respondsToSelector:@selector("afunctioname")]) {
    [self.controller performSelector:@selector("afunctionname")];
}
```

Your customizedCell: MyTableViewCell header

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id controller;
```

In the method cellforRow;

```
MyTableViewCell *aCell = ...
aCell.controller = self
..
return aCell;
```

You can add parameters to this selector if the 'afunctioname' takes parameters. If you have multi parameters, use NSDictionary as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but this didn't work. The `self.controller` part is not available in my custom TableCell.

Comment: you have to set this controller to your customizeCell. I'll update my code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a view and a view *controller*. A view controller's class is `UIViewController` (or a subclass) and it has a property `view` of class `UIView` which it controls and which is the "visible part" of the view controller.

In the method

```
- (void)showUserProfile
{
    id parentView = [self superview];
    [parentView showUserProfile];
}
```

you call `showUserProfile` on the table view cell's superview but *not* on the view controller. As you don't know the internal implementation of a `UITableView` you cannot even be sure that the cell's superview is the same as your table view controller's `view`. In fact, it is not. Because as you can see from the error log the table view itself has a subview of class `UITableViewWrapperView` which contains all the cells. But this view doesn't know anything about the method you declared in your table view controller. That is why the app crashes.

For calling a method in your table view controller you can either declare a delegate as suggested by [tdelepine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25017026/2062785) or you can add an action to your button in your table view controller's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method right after dequeuing the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"yourID"];
    [cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showUserProfile) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // customize other properties of your cell
    return cell;
}
```

This would be the easiest way to go in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for replying; the problem I have with this is that I want to pass a parameter or at least somehow get the selected row in that method. Is there any way I can do this with this approach?

Comment: You can give each of your buttons a tag in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. In order to make it unique you could use the cell's row for example: `cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row`. In the `showUserProfile` method you can then use the `sender` to extract that information, because the sender will be the button: `int row = ((UIButton*)sender).tag`.